# Aurelia: Child Router Navigation: Route not found

Tags: aurelia

Below are my views:
1. `app` - standard
2. `home` - Has a list of items on left, on selection of any, will display some content on the right side in router-view (contract-view to be loaded).
3. `contract-view`

app.ts: route Config:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
        config.title = 'Contracts Portal';
        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', nav: true, title: 'Home' },
            { route: 'resources', name: 'resources', moduleId: 'resources', nav: true, title: 'Resources' },
            { route: 'tools', name: 'tools', moduleId: 'tools', nav: true, title: 'Tools' }
        ]);
        this.router = router;
    }
```

Home.ts Router Config:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
        config.title = "test";
        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'contract-view/:id'], name: 'contract-view', moduleId: 'contract-view', nav: true, title: 'Test' } 
        ]);
        this.router = router;
    }
```

on selection of a item in home page list, I am trying to navigate as below to load content in the right pane's router-view, in `home.ts`:

```
this.router.navigateToRoute("contract-view", { id: 4090 });
```

However it throws the error: Route not found: /contract-view/4090

At this point, it's still home page and default route, hence the url reads: `http://localhost:9000/#/`
and so it fails.
But, if I manually change the url to `http://localhost:9000/#/home` and then select a list item, navigation to contract-view works.
What I am I missing here?

I am looking for absolute path navigation. Tried navigating to `home/contract-view` but fails with error:
A route with name 'home/contract-view' could not be found. Check that name: `home/contract-view` was specified in the route's config.

Answer (score 0):

The default route of Home.ts has a parameter:

```
config.map([
     { route: ['', 'contract-view/:id'], name: 'contract-view', moduleId: 'contract-view', nav: true, title: 'Test' } 
]);
```

This might be a problem because the parameter :id is not referenced in the first name. So, I suggest you change the route as follow:

```
config.map([
     //create another route with no parameters,
     //this route will represent an empty selection of contract
     { route: [ '', 'contract-view' ], name: 'contract-view-empty', moduleId: 'contract-view-empty', Title: 'Select a Contract' } 
     { route: 'contract-view/:id', name: 'contract-view', moduleId: 'contract-view', nav: true, title: 'Test' } 
]);
```

Then, to generate a navigation link you can use `route-href` attr. Like this:

```
<a route-href="route: contract-view; params.bind: { id: 4090 }">Navigate</a>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The default navigation is ok. The issue occurs only when I navigate from viewmodel using this:
`this.router.navigateToRoute("contract-view", { id: 4090 });`
It tries to do relative navigation while url still reads /#/.

Comment: Also, I don't really have a a tag but a div which isn't responding to route-href. So, I am using click.delegate="$parent.select(contract)" and in select function, I am navigating.

Comment: please, provide the html containing the div and select function as well

Comment: `
<ul>
                <li repeat.for="contract of contracts" click.delegate="$parent.select(contract)">
...
</li>
</ul>
`

Comment: can you use `a`? `<ul> <li repeat.for="contract of contracts" > <a click.delegate="$parent.select(contract)"></a> </li> </ul>`

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with Aurelia Router framework. Discussion and workaround here:
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/230